# Calling a method to Expand and Collapse a section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `Simple-Expand`  http://redhotsly.github.com/simple-expand/ to expand and collapse sections in the HTML page.

JQuery code :

```
$(function () {
    $('.hello').simpleexpand();

});

$(function () {
    $('.bye').simpleexpand();

});
```

HTML :

```
<a href='' id='hello' class='hello'> Hi  </a>

            <a href='' id='bye'  class='bye'> Bye  </a>
```

Div :

```
<div class="content">
  Hello
</div>

<div class="content">
  Bye
</div>
```

When i click on the link with the class `hello`, Only the `DIV` tag with the text `Hello` should be called, and when i click on the link `Bye`, the `DIV` tag with the text `Bye` should be displayed. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2):

It is all in the doc you posted : http://sylvain-hamel.github.io/simple-expand/

You have to specify options in your call to the `simpleexpand` method

For example :

```
$(function () {
    $('.hello').simpleexpand({'defaultTarget': '.helloDiv'});

});

$(function () {
    $('.bye').simpleexpand({'defaultTarget': '.byeDiv'});

});
```

and your html :

```
<div class="helloDiv">
  Hello
</div>

<div class="byeDiv">
  Bye
</div>
```

Comment: I think there should be `{}` in the JQuery function, but it doesn't expand or collapse.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

JQuery code :

```
$(function () {
    $('a').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var divId = 'div_' + id;
        $('#'+divId).simpleexpand();
     });
});
```

HTML :

```
<a href='' id='hello'class='hello'> Hi  </a>
<a href='' id='bye' class='bye'> Bye  </a>
```

Div :

```
<div class="content" id='div_hello'>
  Hello
</div>

<div class="content" id='div_bye'>
  Bye
</div>
```

Comment: The JQuery function is getting fired, but it doesn't expand.

Comment: @sharonHwk: please share http://jsfiddle.net/ link, for us see your complete code.

Comment: This is the better solution I believe, but let me illustrate what Aditya is trying to do a little better....